# Autoclicking on javascript button

Tags: javascript, iframe, click

Let's say i got website with simple iframe which loads a website, this page has a javascript button redirecting to other page; is there a way to implement to my main site a script which clicks on that button in website in this iframe ?

regards :)

Comment: Is website in your iframe same domain with main website?

Comment: Nope it's not .

Comment: Hmmm, then it is imposible to do because they are not the same origin. Your browser will restrict this

Comment: I thought that maybe i can extract URL from this JavaScript button and then just load the link ?

Comment: Yes, you can load the link manually if you can extract the URL from iframe website source.